# How do I un-ignore a conversation in Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

In Facebook Messenger, in a conversation with a friend I clicked on the info button (you know, the one that also has "View profile" and stuff) and I clicked "Ignore messages" thinking it just wouldn't alert me if I receive messages from them, but instead it moved them to "Filtered requests". I now want to move it back to my inbox where I can see and unignore this friend. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Search for group by name. It’ll show up at the bottom. When you open the group it’ll have buttons for “reply” or “delete”. Reply rejoins.

Answer (score 0):

Just send him a message and it'll be unignored.