# How do I un-ignore a conversation on Facebook Messenger?

Tags: facebook-messenger

There has already been a [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113261/how-do-i-un-ignore-a-conversation-in-facebook-messenger) like this, however either it is outdated or I'm seeing a special case.

I have ignored someone on Messenger, and want to undo this without actually sending them a message. When I open their conversation from Filtered Messages in the browser version of Facebook, there is no Reply/Delete option. When opening the conversation in the Messenger App, it only gives me one option: "I don't want to hear from [name]"

If I encounter this scenario, how do I undo an ignore?

Answer (score -1):

people (bottom middle), add contacts (top right), requests.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications! This only answers how to reach the message requests view, which isn't what is asked for.